# What is the name of a lime-growing tree?

Tags: single-word-requests

The limetree (linden) doesn't grow limes. What do you call a tree that does?

Comment: Which particular [lime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lime_(fruit))?

Comment: And I've never heard a linden called a limetree (we call them basswood - they don't grow bass either), so there probably isn't a problem where the two overlap, if they overlap.

Comment: [General reference; Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/lime+tree#:~:text=lime%20tree%20%2D%20any%20of%20various%20deciduous%20trees%20of%20the%20genus,tree%2C%20linden%2C%20basswood%2C%20lime).

Comment: @PhilSweet - Lime is the usual name for trees of the genus Tilia in British English, which isn't a problem as the citrus doesn't grow here (except in conservatories).

Comment: @PhilSweet Me neither. I have a linden tree growing in front by the road, and indeed am just one street away from Linden Avenue myself. Nobody calls these trees lime trees.

Answer (score 1):

I think they are called *Lime Trees*. But also *Citrus Trees* or *Citrus aurantifolia* and *keylime*

The most common in the US, is the Mexican Lime. Or

> Mexican key lime (Citrus aurantifolia), also known as key lime,
> bartender's lime, and West Indian lime, is a moderately sized
> evergreen fruit tree.

Comment: The key lime is a different (although similar) fruit to the limes you buy in grocery stores. It grows wild in Florida and Mexico, but it's probably not the kind you'd find planted in somebody's yard.

Comment: Wikipedia says "There are several species of citrus trees whose fruits are called limes, including the Key lime (Citrus aurantiifolia), Persian lime, kaffir lime, and desert lime." So I guess some would be called key lime trees, other Persian lime trees, etc, although many of these also have other names (Persian lime is a hybrid Citrus × latifolia but kaffir is Citrus hystrix, etc). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lime_(fruit)